# Where can I apply for Kurdistan short-term residency?

Tags: uk-citizens, residency, iraqi-kurdistan

For a UK citizen, can the process for a [short-term residency](http://erbilresidency.com/shortterm.php) permit for Kurdistan be started and completed once in Kurdistan (say, for those eligible, in the 15 day visa free period) or must it have started before entry?

Recent first-hand experience preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Kurdistan Government's representation in Spain](http://www.krgspain.org/english-residence/):

> Visitors wishing to extend their stay in the Kurdistan Region beyond a three month period must apply for a Card of Residence.
>   Below is a general outline of the requirements for obtaining a residency card for an extended stay in the Kurdistan Region of Iraq:
>
> - One will need a sponsor/guarantor,
> - Fill out Application
> - Undergo a blood test
> - Provide 2 Photos
> - Clear an investigation
>
> **Pictures and blood tests are performed at the KRG Directorate of Residency offices**. The fee is 36,000 Iraqi Dinars, and the process usually takes approximately 2-3 hours.

There appear to be three KRG Directorate of Residency offices:

1. [Erbil International airport](http://erbilresidency.com/erbilairport.php)
2. [Soran District Office](http://erbilresidency.com/sorandistrict.php)
3. [Haji Omaran Border Checkpoint](http://erbilresidency.com/hajiomaran.php)

Therefore it is impossible to submit the full documentation for a residency permit outside of Kurdistan. Of course, given the current instability in the region it's hard to say if *any* official procedures are being followed.